# Can a dispatch queue be shared between app and extension?

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

Since apps and their extensions run in different processes, can we use dispatch queues to serialize tasks?

App:

```
let queue = DispatchQueue(label:"com.app.queue")
queue.async {
   doSomethingInApp()
}
```

Extension:

```
let queue = DispatchQueue(label:"com.app.queue")
queue.async {
   doSomethingInExtension()
}
```

Does the label serve as a global queue identifier across iOS?

Will it really work and serialize doSomethingInApp() and doSomethingInExtension() ?

And if it does, how apps are protected from each other against potentially deadly queue name collisions?

If if it does not work what could be done instead?

Comment: The label you pass to the queue is only for debugging purposes, passing the same label multiple times doesn't result in you getting the same queue.